# Is it possible to disable a constraint in Oracle using a trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to disable a reference constraint using a trigger in Oracle 11g?

Comment: It depends.  Are the constraint and the trigger on the same table?  If so, then definitely "no".  It sounds like a very, very bad idea either way.  I don't know what your specific technical problem is, but I can almost guarantee that this is NOT how you want to solve it.

Comment: Making a wild guess about what you are trying to achieve, I wonder if a better approach to your problem would be a DEFERRED constraint (i.e. one that is not checked until you commit).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think the DEFERRED constraint will work for me.

Comment: I don't think so,because ALTER TABLE is a DDL which does an implicit commit. Check for deferred constraint